# How to create timer in silverlight application using ironruby?

Tags: silverlight, timer, ironruby

I want to call some function repeatly in client's browser.
System::Timers::Timer work only on serverside how i know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Silverlight you can use [System::Threading::Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or [System::Windows::Threading::DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). If your timer callback is mainly interacting with the UI, use the DispatcherTimer, otherwise use the regular Timer.

Comment: Thank you. All classes from ".NET Framework Class Library for Silverlight" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838194(v=vs.95) are realized in ironruby?

Comment: Yes, all are accessible from IronRuby.